# Multiple network request in activity one after another

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my `Activity` I have to make request 5 times to the server on a click event, one after another and do some processing with the data. This tasks will show a loading message (the task it is currently doing) and a `Progressbar` (for showing the combined tasks progress). So, after completing each request and data processing I will update the loading message and the `Progressbar`. Currently I am thinking about applying it using `Thread` and `Handler`. Is it the best way to do so?

Comment: You probably need an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: If I was doing that I would use RxJava + Retrofit to concatenate the requests and update the progressbar before starting the other request.

Comment: No. I need the response of each request almost sequentially. I don't think AsyncTask is good fit here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use retrofit or volley library to make concurrent request like each request success will make another request

Comment: I don't need to make concurrent request rather sequential. And I am well aware of these libraries.